# Web-Installer for CMS - Config

Tags: php, configuration, content-management-system, installation

Advise me what to do.
I have a file `connect.php`, which includes the file `config.php`.
I want to make the CMS installer.

`Install.php` - User will add a mysql (server login pass dbname) data, and the it will be saved to a file Config.php. How to make it?

Or offer an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about after taking mysql credentials and verifying connection, you generate code for config.php by using php's file function in Install.php. Logic of generating of code for config.php will depend on you use config.php.

Here is the sample code, let say config.php is should look like this.

```
    <?php 
$config['host'] = "localhost";
$config['user'] = "root";
$config['password'] = "password";
    ?>
```

Php code for generating above code will be like.

```
    <?php
$codeStr =<<<CODE <?php  
          \$config['host'] = "$host";
\$config['user'] = "$username";
\$config['password'] = "$password";
file_put_contents('config.php',$codeStr);
CODE;
```

?>

Comment: You don't understood me. User will add mysql settings in web-form, and after that installation will be start.

Comment: After taking information about database from web form in installer.php can't you can create config.php. Based on information posted through web form.

Comment: Welcome :), don't forget add mysql connection validation in web form validation.

Answer (score 2):

How about just writing the file?

```
file_put_contents("config.php", trim(<<<CONFIG
   <?php
    \$config["server"] = '$_FORM[server]';
    \$config["dbname"] = '$_FORM[dbname]';
    ...
   ?>
CONFIG
));
```

Note that the $_FORM data fields should be escaped (addslashes) prior saving.